# 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method gotoAndStop through a reference with static type Class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, class, function, document

I see where i was going wrong however when i change the instance name like you said i 1120: Access of undefined property snakePart. all of this code btw is at document class level and the movieclips are in the library not on stage

Answer (score 1):

Is the instance on the stage? When you name instances, don't name them identical to your class name. Flash gets confused because you're importing a class called SnakePart but you have an instance called ... SnakePart. Instead, name it something else (i.e. snake_part) or at least change the case (i.e. snakePart - not recommended as it can lead to some issues debugging).

Change your instance name, change this code snakePart.gotoAndStop(2) and you should be gravy. Unless your actionscript is in a part of the flash (i.e. on another frame or not in the Document class level - preferred and recommended) that the object hasn't been instantiated yet.

To instantiate a library movieclip, try this in your Document class level, inside your constructor :

```
var snakePart:SnakePart = new SnakePart();
addChild(snakePart);
```

Comment: I see where i was going wrong however when i change the instance name like you said i 1120: Access of undefined property snakePart. all of this code btw is at document class level and the movieclips are in the library not on stage

Comment: Oooh, if your movieclip is just in the library, then you need to instantiate it sir! Edited my answer to help you out with that. Also, it's not an "instance" if it's in the library... that's considered similar to a Class declaration. It's an "instance" if you drag-drop it onto a stage and give it it's instance name OR if you dynamically build it actionscript

Answer (score 0):

You are calling gotoAndStop on the *class* definition "SnakePart" instead of an *instance* of the class, as in `var snake_part:SnakePart = new SnakePart();`

Answer (score 0):

it does what it says on the tin really, you have not defined a static method in the class that you are calling, presumably you are meaning to call an instance of the class instead.